# Bundle product with custom options

Tags: custom-options, bundle-product

Does anyone know any technical reasons as why bundle products with dynamic pricing cannot have custom options?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this is a limitation with Magento.

There is a discussion on their forum visible over here:

[Custom Options on a Bundle Product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14910/P0/)

**The solution is:**

> As a quick solution to add Custom Options to bundled products with
>   dynamic prices you may try to tweak prepareProductSave method in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Observer.php, namely just comment some
>   code out as follows:

```
/*
    if ($product->getPriceType() == '0' && !$product->getOptionsReadonly()) {
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        if ($customOptions = $product->getProductOptions()) {
            foreach (array_keys($customOptions) as $key) {
                $customOptions[$key]['is_delete'] = 1;
            }
            $product->setProductOptions($customOptions);
        }
    }
*/
```

> To get rid of “Bundle with dynamic pricing cannot include custom defined options. Options will not be saved.” message you should hack app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options.phtml template

```
//show error message
/*
if ($('price_type')) {
if ($('price_type').value == '0' && $('dynamic-price-warrning')) {
    $('dynamic-price-warrning').show();
}
}
*/
```

**Obviously this should only be done via local override (i.e do NOT mess with the core files as they mention) to preserve upgradeability**

Comment: This post is about simple product with custom options as a part of bundle product :(. It is not what i need

Comment: @SergeyTsekhanovich did u got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment the file as indicated but in the backend in the Bundle (Bundle Items) tab typing a code of a simple product with options does not come out no result ("no product").
Also, by adding a product with custom options from Database, the product is added to the Bundle but without the options! How can you view them and be able to select them?

Thanks so much