# Is it possible to create a configurable product with bundle product types?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, bundled-product, products-management, recurring

I want to create configurable product with bundle. requirement is for recurring bundle product creation.

For Example:

in simple way if i want to create recurring for simple product, what i do is create 3 product with different frequency attribute values (1 week, 1 months, 2 months)

and using this 3 simple product and i can create one configurable which have 3 recurring options.

So, now i want to create same scenario for bundle product.
but bundle product are not showing in associate products list of configurable product. Any help or guideline is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to use bundle products as simple products inside a configurable product.

In your case, I would try to find another way of selecting frequency. Since you don't need separate inventory management, you could make the frequency a custom option instead of an attribute.

An answer for how to add custom options to bundles can be found here: [Bundle product with custom options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17596/bundle-product-with-custom-options)