# Magento 2 - Is it possible to enable "Customizable Options" feature in Bundle products?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want custom option feature in bundle products in Magento 2. So anyone can help here. How I can enable this feature in admin for bundle product creation.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Magento 2 you are using?

Comment: WE have using Magento 2.3.1

Comment: Did you manage to find anything useful for this?

Comment: Not yet and i tried with another way.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the bundle product don't have this option by default you need to customize the bundle product module or you may check below resources for more information

- extension https://www.itoris.com/magento-2-custom-options.html for "customizeable options"
- https://amirshakya.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/custom-options-on-a-bundle-product-in-dynamic-pricing/
- [Bundle product with custom options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17596/bundle-product-with-custom-options)

Comment: Thanks for details. i will check.